# Error in converting a dotfile to image by graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, dotfiles, anytree

I made a tree graph by anytree module and I want to get a png file out of it. I tried graphviz (dotfile to png) but got an error:
What is the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    BOM.treegraph()
  File "C:\Users\Ali\Downloads\test.test.succ4.py", line 33, in treegraph
    DotExporter (vars()[BOM.a[0].product]).to_picture ('udo.png')
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\anytree\exporter\dotexporter.py", line 232, in to_picture
    check_call(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 342, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Is 'udo.png' in "C:\Users\Ali\Downloads" ?

Comment: yes. I made a white empty png image in "C:\Users\Ali\Downloads"

Comment: Then subprocess inside `.to_picture` is calling some or other script that it can't find

Comment: did you install `dot` and is it in yout path / can it be found by python?

Comment: I've imported DotExporter from anytree.exporter

Comment: You need to install graphviz first: http://www.graphviz.org/ and ensure that dot is in your path. to test it run `dot -?` in your command line